# Using default params for database and adding few new params dynamically generated into database in Grails

Tags: grails

def u = new UserRequests(params)

by this code i am able to save all the value what i am getting from params into database but now i want to add two more parameters which are not part of params into database like

confirmation link thats generated dynamically 
and
isActivated

how can i achieve this without taking burden of my default params coming in request

want to do something like this is it possible

def u = new UserRequests(params,isActive:false,activationLink:"newactivationlink1")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make your code work but implementing your own constructor.  If you don't want to do that though you could do something like this:

```
def u = new UserRequests(params + [isActive:false,activationLink:"newactivationlink1"])
```

Adding your additional properties as a map to the params map.  You probably don't want to modify the params map (which this doesn't).  If you wanted to be more explicit about it you could break it out:

```
def userParams = params + [isActive:false,activationLink:"newactivationlink1"]
def u = new UserRequests(userParams)
```